# How can I display data in Yajra datatables in Laravel 7?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, datatables, laravel-7

I want to display data in Laravel using Yajra Datatables, but the problem is that the data can't synchronise yet.

[image]

[image]

If I do Dump and Die **dd($orders)**, the number of data displayed is 4, but if I show it in the Yajra Datatables, the data displayed will be 5. In this case, the correct data is 4.

How to fix this issue? The following is the code I have created.

**Controller**

```php
public function index(Request $request) {

    if (request()->ajax()) {

        // Query Builder

        $startDate  = Carbon::parse(request()->startDate)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $endDate    = Carbon::parse(request()->endDate)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $orders = DB::connection('database_marketplace')->table('category')
                ->join('product', 'category.id', '=', 'product.category_id')
                ->join('order_summary', 'product.id', '=', 'order_summary.product_id')
                ->join('order', 'order_summary.order_id', '=', 'order.id')
                ->where('category.id', 6)
                ->where('order.order_status', 2)
                ->when(request()->startDate || request()->endDate, function($q) use ($startDate, $endDate) {
                    $q->whereBetween('order.created_at', [$startDate, $endDate]);
                })
                ->select('product.id', 'product.name', 'product.price', 'product.description', 'product.created_at', 'product.updated_at', DB::raw('sum(order_summary.quantity) as quantity'))
                ->groupBy('product.id')
                ->get();

        // End Query Builder

        // dd($orders);

        return DataTables::of($orders)
            ->addIndexColumn()
            ->editColumn('name', function($item) {
                return $item->name;
            })
            ->editColumn('order_count', function ($item) {
                return $item->quantity;
            })
            ->editColumn('ingredient', function($item) {
                $data = \Str::between($item->description, 'Bahan-bahan:', 'Cara Membuat');

                return nl2br($data);
            })
            ->rawColumns(['name', 'order_count', 'ingredient'])
            ->make(true);
    }
    return view('admin.marketplace.shoppingList.index', [
        'title'     => 'Belanja',
        'subtitle'  => 'Daftar Belanja',
        'date'      => $request->date ?? null,
        'startDate' => $request->startDate ?? null,
        'endDate'   => $request->endDate ?? null,
    ]);
}
```

Blade View

```html
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('title', "{$title}")
@section('styles')
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;0,600;0,700;1,400;1,600;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />
<style>
    table thead th {
        font-family: 'Nunito Sans';
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 13px;
        line-height: 18px;
        /* stroke */
        color: #676767;
    }
    table tbody tr td {
        font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 13px;
        line-height: 18px;
        color: #676767;
    }
    .toolbar {
        float: right;
    }
    .date-filter {
        float: left;
    }
</style>
@endsection
@section('content')
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header d-flex justify-content-between">
        <h4 class="text-dark">
            {{ $subtitle }}
        </h4>
        {{--
        <div class="d-flex">
            --}}
            <form class="form-inline" action="{{ route('marketplace.shoppingList.index') }}" method="GET">
                <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
                    <label for="dateFilter" class="sr-only">Filter</label>
                    <input type="text" id="dateFilter" max="{{ date('Y-m-d') }}" class="form-control rounded mr-2" value="{{ old('date') ? old('date') : $date }}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="startDate" id="startDate" value="{{ old('startDate') ? old('startDate') : $startDate  }}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="endDate" id="endDate" value="{{ old('endDate') ? old('endDate') : $endDate  }}">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-100 rounded">
                Submit
                </button>
            </form>
            {{-- <a href="#" id="export" class="btn btn-primary w-100 rounded">Download PDF</a> --}}
            {{--
        </div>
        --}}
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table id="table-order" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width: 100%">
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer bg-whitesmoke">
        Panen-panen Admin
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
@section('modal')
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
    });

    $(function() {
        oTable = $('#table-order').DataTable({
            "columnDefs": [{
                "defaultContent": "-",
                "targets": "_all"
            }],
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: {
                url: '{{url()->current()}}'
            },
            columns: [
                {
                    data: 'DT_RowIndex',
                    name: 'DT_RowIndex',
                    orderable: false,
                    searchable: false,
                    title: 'No',
                    width: '5%',
                },
                {
                    data: 'name',
                    name: 'name',
                    title: 'Nama Produk',
                    width: '45%'
                },
                {
                    data: 'order_count',
                    name: 'order_count',
                    title: 'Jumah Pesanan',
                    width: '10%'
                },
                {
                    data: 'ingredient',
                    name: 'ingredient',
                    title: 'Bahan-bahan',
                    width: '40%'
                },
            ],
        });
    });
</script>

{{-- Date time Range Picker --}}
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#dateFilter').daterangepicker({
            opens: 'left',
            autoUpdateInput: false,
            minDate: '2021-01-01 00:00:00',
            timePicker: true,
            timePicker24Hour: true,
            locale: {
                cancelLabel: 'Clear',
                format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
            },
        });

        $('#dateFilter').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
            $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss') + ' - ' + picker.endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
            $('#startDate').val(picker.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
            $('#endDate').val(picker.endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
        });

        $('#dateFilter').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
            $(this).val('');
        });
    });
</script>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

```php
public function index(Request $request)
{
    
    if (request()->ajax()) {

        //Query Builder

        $startDate  = Carbon::parse(request()->startDate)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $endDate    = Carbon::parse(request()->endDate)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        
        $orders = DB::connection('database_marketplace')->table('category')
                ->join('product', 'category.id', '=', 'product.category_id')
                ->join('order_summary', 'product.id', '=', 'order_summary.product_id')
                ->join('order', 'order_summary.order_id', '=', 'order.id')
                ->where('category.id', 6)
                ->where('order.order_status', 2)
                ->when(request()->startDate || request()->endDate, function($q) use ($startDate, $endDate) {
                    $q->whereBetween('order.created_at', [$startDate, $endDate]);
                })
                ->select('product.id', 'product.name', 'product.price', 'product.description', 'product.created_at', 'product.updated_at', DB::raw('sum(order_summary.quantity) as quantity'))
                ->groupBy('product.id')
                ->orderBy('name','asc')
                ->get();

        //End Query Builder

        // dd($orders);

        return DataTables::of($orders)
            ->addIndexColumn()
            ->editColumn('name', function($item) {
                return $item->name;
            })  
            ->editColumn('quantity', function ($item) {
                return $item->quantity;
            })
            ->editColumn('ingredient', function($item) {
                $data = \Str::between($item->description, 'Bahan-bahan:','Cara Membuat');

                return nl2br($data);
            })
            ->rawColumns(['name','quantity', 'ingredient'])
            ->make(true);
    }

    return view('admin.marketplace.shoppingList.index',[
        'title'     => 'Belanja',
        'subtitle'  => 'Daftar Belanja',
        'date'      => $request->date ?? null,
        'startDate' => $request->startDate ?? null,
        'endDate'   => $request->endDate ?? null
    ]);
}
```

blade.php

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
    });
    
    $(function() {
        oTable = $('#table-order').DataTable({
            "columnDefs": [{
                "defaultContent": "-",
                "targets": "_all"
            }],
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: {
                url: '{{url()->current()}}'
            },
            columns: [
                {
                    data: 'DT_RowIndex',
                    name: 'DT_RowIndex',
                    orderable: false,
                    searchable: false,
                    title: 'No',
                    width: '5%',
                },
                {
                    data: 'name',
                    name: 'name',
                    title: 'Nama Produk',
                    width: '45%'
                },
                {
                    data: 'quantity',
                    name: 'quantity',
                    title: 'Jumah Pesanan',
                    width: '15%'
                },
                {
                    data: 'ingredient',
                    name: 'ingredient',
                    title: 'Bahan-bahan',
                    width: '35%'
                },
            ],
        });    
        
        $('#dateFilter').daterangepicker({
            opens: 'left',
            autoUpdateInput: false,
            minDate: '2021-01-01 00:00:00',
            timePicker: true,
            timePicker24Hour: true,
            locale: {
                cancelLabel: 'Clear',
                format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
            },
        });
    
        $('#dateFilter').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
            $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss') + ' - ' + picker.endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
            $('#startDate').val(picker.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
            $('#endDate').val(picker.endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
    
            //sent as ajax request (startDate and endDate) to server
            oTable.ajax.url('{{url()->current()}}?startDate=' + $('#startDate').val() + '&endDate=' + $('#endDate').val()).load();
    
            //reload datatable
            oTable.ajax.reload();
        });
        
        //Reset date filter
        $('#dateFilter').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
            $(this).val('');
            $('#startDate').val('');
            $('#endDate').val('');
    
            //sent as ajax request (startDate and endDate) to server
            oTable.ajax.url('{{url()->current()}}').load();
    
            //reload datatable
            oTable.ajax.reload();
        });
    
        //Export current data to PDF
        $('#export').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var startDate = $('#startDate').val();
            var endDate = $('#endDate').val();

            if (startDate == '' || endDate == '') {
                alert('Silahkan pilih tanggal terlebih dahulu');
            } else {
                // Sent to route name shoppingList.export
                window.location.href = '{{ route('marketplace.shoppingList.export') }}?startDate=' + startDate + '&endDate=' + endDate, '_blank';
            }

        });
    });
    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

Blade view

```
<table class="table align-middle table-hover table-nowrap mb-0"
       id="table_id"
       role="grid"
       aria-describedby="example2_info"
       style="width:100%"
>
    <thead class="table-light">
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Job Position</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="list form-check-all">
    </tbody>
</table>
...
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        let dataTable = $('#table_id').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            autoWidth: false,
            filter: false,
            bLengthChange: false,
            responsive: true,
            language: {
                processing: '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i><span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>'
            },
            ajax: {
                url: "{{ url('/your route goes here') }}",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "GET",
                data: function(d) {
                    d.filter_val = $('.search').val(),
                    d.search = $('input[type="search"]').val()
                }
            },
            columns: [
                {
                    data: "DT_RowIndex",
                    width: "3%"
                }, {
                    data: "name"
                }, {
                    data: "email"
                }, {
                    data: "job_position"
                }, {
                    data: "phone"
                }, {
                    data: "action",
                    orderable: false,
                    searchable: false
                }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Controller side - Method to send data

```php
public function methodName(Request $request)
{
    $data = ModelName::select('id', 'name', 'email', 'job_position', 'phone')->get();

    if ( $request->ajax() ) {
        return Datatables::of($data)
            ->addIndexColumn()
            ->addColumn('action', function ($row) {
                return '<button href="" data-id="' . $row->id . '" onclick="edit(this)"  class="btn btn-outline-info btn-icon waves-effect waves-light shadow-none btn-sm me-1" id="edit_contact" target="_blank"> <i class=" ri-pencil-fill"></i> </button>';                  

            })->rawColumns(['action'])
            ->make(true);
    }
    
    return view('blade-file-name'));
}
```